# Doubletap-to-Zoom in Android

Tags: java, android, zooming

I have a question to a doubletap-to-zoom action.
With the GestureDetector I got a list of gestures like the doubletap function:

```
@Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent event)
    {
        //Scrollanimation
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "");

        }
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "onDoubleTap: ");
        return true;
    }
```

Now I want to implement a scroll function that enables a scale function by scrolling. How can I implement a scale effect without a scale detector that has to be extended by my MainClass?

Answer (score 1):

DoubleTap is for something like that:

- finger down,
- finger up,
- finger down,
- finger up //end of interaction and here event is send `onDoubleTap`

but `ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener` will provide you callbacks in two scenarios:

**One:**

- two fingers down, `onScaleBegin`
- moving two fingers (scaling) `onScale`
- end of interaction `onScaleEnd`

**Second:**

- one finger down
- one finger up (quick)
- one finger down
- moving finger  `onScaleBegin` and `onScale`
- one finger up `onScaleEnd`

The second allows you to scale with one finger.